# C++ Sockets Connection structure of multiple clients

Tags: c++, sockets

This is a socket program that allows multiple connections, and it seems to be successful, but the CPU usage is really high when more clients connect to host.

this is host's code

```cpp
#include <WINSOCK2.H>
#include <windows.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "sendImg.cpp"
#include <thread>
#define PORT           5150

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int client_quan = 0;

void handle_connections();
void handle_clients(const int client_id);
void test();

Mat frame;


VideoCapture cap;      



int main() {

    cap.open(0);           


    thread handle_conns_thread(handle_connections);
    handle_conns_thread.join();


    return 0;
}

void handle_connections(){
    // Initialize Windows socket library
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsaData); //Winsock version2.2

    //store the info of socket
    SOCKADDR_IN local;
    SOCKADDR_IN client;


    int iaddrSize = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);

    //setting socket (local/internet/ipv4/ipv6, UDP/TCP, socket protocol)
    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    local.sin_family = AF_INET; //TCP
    local.sin_port = htons(PORT); //convert Host Byte Order to Network Byte Order
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); //any address
    //bind(int sock, (struct sockaddr *)address, socklen_t address_len);
    bind(sListen, (struct sockaddr *) &local, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

    listen(sListen, 1);


    while(client_quan<=15){
        sClient[client_quan] = accept(sListen, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &iaddrSize); //block here
        printf("Accepted client:%s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr),
               ntohs(client.sin_port));
        thread handle_handle_clients_thread(handle_clients, client_quan); 
        handle_handle_clients_thread.detach();
        client_quan++;
    }
}

void handle_clients(const int client_id){
    while (true) {
        cap>>frame;
        imshow("Send Image", frame);
        sendImg(frame, client_id);
        waitKey(100);
    }
}


void sendImg(Mat frame, int client_quan){
    imencode(".jpg", frame, data_encode, {CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 50}); // convert img to string
    int len_encode = data_encode.size(); //get string length
    string len = to_string(len_encode); //convert int to string(for sending)
    int length = len.length(); //get string length
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 - length; i++) //client side receive 10 chars first
    {
        len = len + " ";
    }
    while(client_quan>=0){
        send(sClient[client_quan], len.c_str(), strlen(len.c_str()), 0); //send length first
        char send_char[1]; // the type needs char[]
        // send it char by char
        for (int i = 0; i < len_encode; i++)
        {
            send_char[0] = data_encode[i];
            send(sClient[client_quan], send_char, 1, 0); // send
        }
        client_quan--;
    }

}
```

this is client's code

```cpp
#include <WINSOCK2.H>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
//定義程式中使用的常數
#define SERVER_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1" //伺服器端IP地址
#define PORT           5150         //伺服器的埠號
#define MSGSIZE        10000         //收發緩衝區的大小
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using  namespace  std;
using  namespace  cv;

Mat recvImg();
void handle_connections();

// Declare socket
SOCKET sClient;
char recvBuf[16]; // used to save the length of string
char recvBuf_1[1]; // save data char by char
vector<u_char> data; // used to load sent data
Mat img_decode(0,3,CV_32FC1); // save result

float fx = 1.5;
float fy = 1.5;
int main()
{
    handle_connections();
    while (TRUE) {
        Mat img_decode = recvImg();
        imshow("Received Image", img_decode);
        //TODO: finish stream transmit(change pic into the img that cam read)
        waitKey(100);
    }
    // 釋放連線和進行結束工作
    closesocket(sClient);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

Mat recvImg(){

    if (recv(sClient, recvBuf, 10, 0))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if (recvBuf[i]<'0' || recvBuf[i]>'9') recvBuf[i] = ' '; // save length
        }
        data.resize(atoi(recvBuf)); //convert string to int
        for (int i = 0; i < atoi(recvBuf); i++){
            recv(sClient, recvBuf_1, 1, 0); //load data char by char
            data[i] = recvBuf_1[0];

        }
        img_decode = imdecode(data, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);  // decode when transmit done
        //resize(img_decode, img_decode, Size(), fx, fy, INTER_CUBIC);
        return img_decode;
    }
}


void handle_connections(){
    // Initialize Windows socket library
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsaData); // Winsock version2.2
    
    //store the info of server socket
    SOCKADDR_IN server;

    //setting socket (local/internet/ipv4/ipv6, UDP/TCP, socket protocol)
    sClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)); //先將儲存地址的server置為全0

    server.sin_family = PF_INET; //TCP
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT); //convert Host Byte Order to Network Byte Order
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_ADDRESS); //convert address to binary
    connect(sClient, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    cout<< "connected to Server";
}
```

What I've done is using a thread that always waiting for new connection, and start a new thread to handle client when there is new connection(constantly send image to it). Is there a way I can do it in a more resource-efficient way?(When the number of clients is 4~5, the program will gradually crash... and what I want to achieve is a local network tool similar to a screen broadcasting system)

**strong text**

Comment: There's obviously much more code than what's shown above. Why do you believe the problem must be in the shown code, and not in all the rest of the code that's not shown here?

Comment: You end your post with a very bold assertion. Very, very bold.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for replying, and I add the code of function "SendImg" and complete client code

Answer (score 0):

```
send(sClient[client_quan], len.c_str(), strlen(len.c_str()), 0);
    //send length first
```

Return value from `send()` gets ignored.

```
// ...

send(sClient[client_quan], send_char, 1, 0);
```

Return value ignored also, and this loop `send()`s one byte at a time. This is horribly inefficient and is the obvious reason for the high CPU load. MS-Windows' threading implemenation has a reputation for being rather inefficient, and having multiple threads constantly switch to and from the kernel mode, just to send one byte to a socket, wastes a lot of CPU time.

The return value of both this`send()` and the `send()` of the length count is completely ignored. This is also a bug, as well. The bug with the initial `send()` of the length goes unnoticed since the initial socket has a fairly large unused empty buffer at the beginning. But that's still a bug.

When reading and writing from network sockets:

1. Both reading and writing should use large buffers.
2. The return value from read, write, send, or recv, ***must always*** be checked to determine how many bytes were actually read and written, and the application ***must*** have correct logic to update its buffers, pointers, etc., to reflect how much data was actually procesesd.

The shown code already has the entire chunk of data to write to the socket, in a buffer. Why send it one one character at a time, then? The shown code should simply prepend the length, then try to send ***everything*** all at once, then check how many characters were actually sent, then attempt to send the rest of the buffer, and so on, until the entire image gets sent.